# Command ViewPager Button OnClick from an Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, retrofit, android-pageradapter

I have create a `ViewPager` in my Android Application, this is the code

```js
public class TestPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<PagerModel> pagerArr;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TestPagerAdapter(Context context, List<PagerModel> pagerArr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pagerArr = pagerArr;
        inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagerArr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up,container,false);

        TextView text_task=view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        TextView text_child_parent=view.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        TextView edit_child_parent=view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView text_deadline=view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        TextView text_avancement=view.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        Button button_update=view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Spinner s = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ImageView rl=view.findViewById(R.id.imm11);

        view.setTag(position);
        ((ViewPager)container).addView(view);
        PagerModel model=pagerArr.get(position);

        text_task.setText(model.getText_task());
        text_avancement.setText(model.getText_avancement());
        text_deadline.setText(model.getText_deadline());
        text_child_parent.setText(model.getText_child_parent());
        edit_child_parent.setText(model.getEdit_child_parent());
        button_update.setText(model.get_button_text());

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
    }

}
```

I want to consume a web service using `Retrofit` when I click on `button_update`,,, how can I access to this button In my `MainActivity` ? Or can I consume my web service from `TestPagerAdapter` ?

This is `MainActivity`

```js
 final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {


                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pager_layout);

                final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
                final Button button_update = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

                final LayoutInflater factory2 = getLayoutInflater();
                final View textEntryView2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
                final Spinner s = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


                String d= DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", date.getTime()).toString();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(getString(R.string.BaseUrl))
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

                    final MyInterface myInterface=retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);

                    Call<List<Task>> call = myInterface.getTask(d);

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
                            final List<Task> TaskList = response.body();
                            if(!TaskList.isEmpty()){

                                List<PagerModel> pageArr = new ArrayList<>();
                                for(int i=0;i<TaskList.size();i++){
                                    pageArr.add(new PagerModel(TaskList.get(0).getDescription(),"Parent",TaskList.get(0).getOwner(),TaskList.get(0).getDeadline(),TaskList.get(0).getAvancement(),"Update Task"));
                                    }


                                TestPagerAdapter adapter44=new TestPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,pageArr);
                                AutoScrollViewPager pager= dialog.findViewById(R.id.pager);

                                pager.setAdapter(adapter44);

                                CirclePageIndicator indicator=dialog.findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
                                indicator.setViewPager(pager);
                                indicator.setCurrentItem(0);
                                dialog.show();}
                            else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"il y'a pas de task pour cette date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            ////////////update

                            button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"woooow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  
                                    
                                    Call<Success> call22= myInterface.UpdateTask(TaskList.get(0).getId(),s.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                    call22.enqueue(new Callback<Success>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Success> call, Response<Success> response) {
                                            Success success = response.body();
                                            int s=success.getCode();

                                            if(s==0)  Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            else {
                                                Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(),"Success update",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                dialog.dismiss(); }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call<Success> call, Throwable t) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });


                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

But I can't access to `button_update`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach how `Adapter` communicate with `Activity` is with `Listener`, which you `Activity` has to `implements` , something like that:

```
public TestPagerAdapter(Context context, List<PagerModel> pagerArr, InteractionListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pagerArr = pagerArr;
        this.listener = listener
        inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    }

public interface InteractionListener{

    void onUpdateClick();

}
```

When the button is tapped you can notify the `Activity` :

```
button_update.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onUpdateClick();
    }
});
```

Than in the `Activity` you can call your `WebService`, but please do it not directly in your `Activity`, but move this logic inside your `Repository`

If you have some questions, just ask

Answer (score 0):

As the pager adapter creates control dynamically you won't have control over the button directly. But to have control on the button click event, you can create some kind of custom event inside your pagerAdapter and then subscribe to that event in your main activity.

And in your adapter you can handle the click of button and raise the event you created in adapter. the event will send the handle to the method which is there in your mainActivity.